# colcon build doesn't generate executables

Tags: ros, ros2, ament, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get started with ROS2 Humble and when running colcon build no executable files are created.

My project structure looks like this:

```
examples
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── package.xml
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── helloWorld.cpp
```

File contents:

examples/CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(examples LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(src)

ament_package()
```

examples/src/CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(helloWorld helloWorld.cpp)
```

examples/helloWorld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

Running `colcon build` in my workspace root succeeds but no executable `helloWorld` is generated. However, when I edit examples/CMakeLists.txt like this, it DOES work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(examples LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)

#add_subdirectory(src)
add_executable(helloWorld "src/helloWorld.cpp") #add executable directly instead

ament_package()
```

This successfully generates the executable and works with `ros2 run`.

It looks like `add_subdirectory` doesn't work correctly... probably has to do something with ament... does anyone know how to do this correctly? I usually strcuture my CMake projects with `add_subdirectory` and want this to work with ROS as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412757/colcon-build-doesn%27t-generate-executables/) by [user334478](https://answers.ros.org/users/140230/user334478/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the required targets. For more about this see this link: https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Publisher-And-Subscriber.html#cmakelists-txt

```
add_executable(helloWorld src/helloWorld.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(helloWorld)

install(TARGETS
  helloWorld
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME})
```

should do the trick for your simple example

---

Originally posted by [GeorgNo](https://answers.ros.org/users/44912/georgno/) with karma: 183 on 2023-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1